# Find if 4 lines form a Quadrilateral in 2D space

Tags: linear-algebra, polygons

- How can I know if 4 lines form a Quadrilateral in 2D space?
- And how would I obtain the corners? (in clockwise order starting with the top left corner)

Note that lines are formed by 2 points in my case, however the length is not limited to those points but goes on infinitly.

All points are in a fixed 2D space, say (0, 0, 100, 100). The Quadrilateral is either in that space too, or I do not care about it. Also lines are hardly ever parralel since the data comes from an actual image.

[image]

The blue lines here is the data, and the green points are the corners I want to obtain. Note that my input data is not always this nice, but mostly consists of lines which do not form any quadrangle in the fixed space.

**What I tried**

- Find all intersection points within that space.
- Create a convex hull

But this seems inefficient to me and is sometimes inaccurate. I was hoping that there is a somewhat better approach.

Comment: 2D, 3D or n-D? How are your lines defined: point+vector, point+point...? Please, try to be more specific. This will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @AugSB You are right. I am sorry, I have added some context.

Comment: @mvw A quandrangle is a name often used for a `quadrilateral`. So yes, just a polygon with four edges. The constraint: that it lies in a 2D plane is just an requirement on its own.

Comment: @mvw Actually yes, I have to find the homography of this quadrangle (if the lines represent an quadrangle at all). More info in a previous question of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724967/largest-four-line-segments-of-polygon

Comment: @mvw But I actually have already the four lines, that is not really the problem. Now I just need to test and form the quadrilateral from them. I appreciate your thinking though!

Comment: Four lines in general position always form a quadrilateral.

Comment: I assumed in my answer that you are looking for a _convex_ quadrilateral. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the lines $L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4$, and let $P_{ij}$ be the intersection of lines $L_i$ and $L_j$. Then the quadrilateral is determined uniquely by which of the lines $L_2,L_3,L_4$ is opposite $L_1$. So there are only three possibilities:

- $L_2$ is opposite $L_1$: $P_{13}P_{32}P_{24}P_{41}$
- $L_3$ is opposite $L_1$: $P_{12}P_{23}P_{34}P_{41}$
- $L_4$ is opposite $L_1$: $P_{12}P_{24}P_{43}P_{31}$

If none of the lines are parallel, and no three lines meet at a single point, then exactly one of these will be a convex quadrilateral.

Do you know how to determine whether a quadrilateral $ABCD$ is convex?

Comment: Yes, if the diagonals intersect. Thank you for your answer. I was indeed looking for a convex quadrilateral.